# Circuits Homework Question

Tags: circuit-analysis

### [image: problem]

So I'm doing my Circuits homework and I got to the circuit above.

Obviously \$i_4\$ would have to be 1A, because of KCL.  However going further along, I can't find a way to make \$i_3\$ positive!

I don't want you guys doing my homework for me (I need to learn!) but I was just wondering if it would be possible for \$i_3\$ to be -1A?  The far-left element needs another ampere from somewhere.

Comment: First: you use the correct 'mode' for a homework-related question: state it is homework, state what you have done so far, and ask for a (small) next step, not for a cut-n-paste answer. Now for your problem: obviously i4 and i3 can't both be positive, so you seem to be on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, \$i_3\$ is -1A. It's possible to have a negative current. That just means that \$i_3\$ actually flows in the opposite direction initially assumed.

Comment: Thank you!  I just wanted to make sure it was possible and not something I'm missing.